# In less, what's the matter with the <End> key as command?

Tags: less

In `less` I have been using the <kbd>End</kbd> key as a command for many years.

This is in order to let `less` end working page by page but instead to let `less` make its work up to the end of the file from that position on.

Thus I can next morning see all the results in only a few seconds: jump to the beginning of the file and then search for something.

So far all is ok

But now I saw in the manpage, the <kbd>End</kbd> key is not mentioned (besides for editing lines).

1. What's the matter?
2. Is there an equivalent key sequence available for the same effect?

   (I do not want to use `+G` option).
3. After I have typed the <kbd>End</kbd> key, is there a way to undo this?